# trying to connect graphql to postgress how to define user and pass?

Tags: postgresql, graphql

I fail to receive information from my postgres db when trying to connect with graphql.

I receive the following response:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "password authentication failed for user \"admin\"",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "account"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "account": null
  }
}
```

I honestly don't know where to define the user and pass.

```
const express = require('express');
const expressGraphQL = require('express-graphql');
const schema = require('./schema');
const app = express();

app.use('/graphql', expressGraphQL({
   schema,
   graphiql: true
}))
app.listen(4000, () => {
   console.log('Listening...')
})
```

and this is my schema file

```
const graphql = require('graphql');
const connectionString = 'myURI';
const pgp = require('pg-promise')();
const db = {}
db.conn = pgp(connectionString);
const {
   GraphQLObjectType,
   GraphQLID,
   GraphQLString,
   GraphQLBoolean,
   GraphQLList,
   GraphQLSchema
} = graphql;
const AccountType = new GraphQLObjectType({
   name: 'account',
   fields: () => ({
      id: { type: GraphQLID },
      name: { type: GraphQLString },
      busines_name: { type: GraphQLString },
      email: {
         type: new GraphQLList(EmailType),
         resolve(parentValue, args) {
            const query = `SELECT * FROM "emails" WHERE
            account=${parentValue.id}`;
            return db.conn.many(query)
               .then(data => {
                  return data;
               })
               .catch(err => {
                  return 'The error is', err;
               });
         }
      }
   })
})
const EmailType = new GraphQLObjectType({
   name: 'Email',
   fields: {
      id: { type: GraphQLID },
      email: { type: GraphQLString },
      primary: { type: GraphQLBoolean }
   }
})
const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
   name: 'RootQueryType',
   fields: {
      account: {
      type: AccountType,
      args: { id: { type: GraphQLID } },
      resolve(parentValue, args) {
         const query = `SELECT * FROM "account" WHERE id=${args.id}`;
         return db.conn.one(query)
            .then(data => {
               return data;
            })
            .catch(err => {
                return 'The error is', err;
            });
      }
   },
   emails: {
      type: EmailType,
      args: { id: { type: GraphQLID } },
      resolve(parentValue, args) {
         const query = `SELECT * FROM "emails" WHERE id=${args.id}`;
         return db.conn.one(query)
            .then(data => {
               return data;
            })
            .catch(err => {
               return 'The error is', err;
            });
        }
      }
   }
})
module.exports = new GraphQLSchema({
   query: RootQuery
})
```

I would like to know where to define the user and the password for the db of what i'm doing wrong besides that.

Comment: Maybe don't use `pg-promise` but the original `pg` module (it has full promise support now). Then the documentation should be very helpful: https://node-postgres.com/features/connecting#programmatic

Comment: @Herku The error is with connectivity, which got nothing to do with the driver layer. And pg-promise is much more than just promises. So you are suggesting to change library, on an unrelated issue, because you know nothing about it in the first place. How helpful!

Comment: @vitaly-t Hi thanks for awesome `pg-promise`! 80% of questions on stack overflow are from people using advanced libaries and technologies that they don't understand enough to find answer to their questions with the documentation. Therefore it is often helpful to learn the underlying technology first - in this case `pg`. I am sure that `pg-promise` is a very good high level library with many interesting abstractions. But the fact that its documentation does not spend much effort on the connection part is a sign for me that there is a strong mismatch between the perspective of OP and the libary.

Comment: @vitaly-t Eventually to become good developers people will have to learn find answers to their problems themselves instead of posting "fix my code" questions. I could give a similar answer like the provided one but this might not be the right answer in all situations. E.g. in production using the environment variable setup is much better. Adding the URI string to the code exposes possibility that it is checked in to source control. Instead people have to learn to identify the problem, find possible solutions and then pick the most suited solution for their situation.

Comment: This guy simply fails to set up connection parameters right, which for `pg` and `pg-promise` are set in the exact same way. In fact, he gets the descriptive error, but still fails to act upon it, posting another fix-it request here.

Answer (score 0):

`const connectionString = 'myURI';`
It should be enough if your connection string includes the username and password. Is your DB connection string of the form postgres://username:password@server:5432 ?
See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING